# How do you set the initial viewing position of a webview?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

In android, I am loading a large United States map from the web inside a webview.

The map is very large and what I would like to do is have the page pre-centered and possibly even pre-zoomed in on a certain part of the map.

For example, in an earlier part of my app the user types in a zip code.  I would like the
webview to be autofocused on that area of the map.

Please don't suggest using google maps!

Comment: How are we supposed to know without knowing what website, what map, or anything about what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you want your map to be centered in pointed place. 
WebView exposes few methods which allow you to get current scale, zoom in/out and scroll.
So you have to do some math and use them to scroll and zoom to certain part.